# Are there minimum criteria for a programming language being Turing complete?

Tags: computability, programming-languages, turing-machines, turing-completeness

Does there exist a set of programming language constructs in a programming language in order for it to be considered Turing Complete?

From what I can tell from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness), the language needs to support recursion, or, seemingly, must be able to run without halting. Is this all there is to it?

Comment: Perhaps your question should ask "Is there a minimal set of programming constructs ...?", because as it is phrased the answer is "All the computable ones."

Comment: Related questions on [so]: [Practical non-Turing-complete languages?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/315340) [What are the practical limitations of a non-turing complete language like Coq?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3492188)

Comment: @DaveClarke, thanks, I've updated that. I do find that your comment begs the question somewhat, although I assume it's because my language is poor. I meant to ask whether or not there are a few operations that if a language could compute, it would be turing equivalent.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I always though that [$\mu$-recursive functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-recursive_function) nailed it. Here is what defines the whole set of computable functions; it is the smallest set of functions containing resp. closed against:

1. The constant $0$ function
2. The successor function
3. Selecting parameters
4. Function composition
5. Primitive Recursion
6. The $\mu$-operator (look for the smallest $x$ such that...)

Check above link for details; you see that it makes for a very compact programming language. It is also horrible to program in -- no free lunch. If you drop any of those, you will lose full power, so it is a minimal set of axioms.

You can translate those quite literally into basic syntactical elements for *WHILE programs*, namely

1. The constant `0`
2. Incrementation `_ + 1`
3. Variable access `x`
4. Program/statement concatenation `_; _`
5. Countdown loops `for ( x to 0 ) do _ end`
6. While loops `while ( x != 0 ) do _ end`

Comment: I think it's obvious that you **cannot** drop the 5th rule in the language. Since the `while` loop in 6 compares to the constant zero, variables can only be incremented by rule 2 and there are no negative constants to start from (rule 1), the `while` loop in 6 is either not entered (x=0) or it's infinite (x>0, and loop body cannot decrease it).

Comment: @MSalters I think you are right; for the simulation I seem to have had in mind, we need `_ - 1` and I can not think of a way to implement that without `for`. Thanks for catching that! (What is "better" -- including `_ - 1` or `for`? Hmm.)

Comment: @Raphael: Not to intrude on a long-forgotten thread, but to my mind, "the language must have a decrement" feels like a much more natural requirement than "the language must be able to express two different kinds of loops, one of which coincidentally causes a variable to be decremented." But that's just my personal taste.

Answer (score 28):

> Does there exist a set of computations that need to be performable in a programming language in order for it to be considered Turing Complete?

Yes, in order to be considered Turing complete a programming language needs to be able to perform any computation that can be performed by a Turing machine. So as a minimum requirement one might say, you need to be able to implement an universal Turing machine - or an interpreter for any other Turing complete language - in it.

> From what I can tell from wikipedia, the language needs to support recursion, or, seemingly, must be able to run without halting. Is this all there is to it?

No. For example a language where the only allowed operation is recursion (i.e. the only possible function you can write is `f(x) = f(x)`), is not Turing complete because all you can write in it are programs that never terminate. As I said earlier, a Turing complete language needs to be able to implement any computation that can be performed by a Turing machine. So clearly that does not suffice.

Also a language doesn't have to support recursion in the way you're thinking of. Just an unrestricted way of expressing loops. That might be recursion, but it might also be a while-loop or goto. A language that doesn't have functions at all can still be Turing complete. And again loops or recursive functions aren't a sufficient condition. You still need a way to execute different code depending on a condition and a way to calculate new values from old ones (otherwise all loops/recursion would either be infinite or not run at all).

---

As for whether there's a minimal set of of necessary and sufficient operations, such that any language that supports these operations is Turing complete and any language that doesn't is not: No, there isn't (unless you define "operation" so vaguely, that it becomes meaningless):

For example as I already said, there are Turing complete languages that don't support recursive functions (or any functions at all). Those can still be Turing complete if they have a `goto` statement or `while` loop (and a way to store arbitrary amounts of data). However a language with recursive functions needs neither `while` nor `goto` to be Turing complete. So `goto` would not be in the set of necessary sufficient operations, but there are languages that are no longer Turing complete if you remove `goto`. Thus there is no such set.

Comment: The only part I'm not certain on is your answer to the minimal set of necessary operations.  You seem to limit your definition of operations to [Control Structures](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Control_structures) which seems to be a much narrower scope than asked, and beyond your own requirement of not defining them "so vaguely, that [they] become meaningless".

Comment: @JoshuaDrake I'm not sure what you mean. I'm not limiting operations to control structures. It's just that I don't talk about any operations that aren't control structures in my counter example because they're not relevant to the example. Actually I do mention "a way to store arbitrary amounts of data" - that's hardly a control structure.

Comment: You make the point that some languages support Turing Completeness with `goto` but that some do not, seemingly claiming that because some use it and some do not that `goto` then cannot be part of a set of operations required for Turing completeness.  My point is that `goto` is simply a syntactical way of implementing a particular more generic operation, such as a jump.  Therefore I believe that if you simply abstracted away from specific control structures you would move closer to a set of operations that would at least point toward Turing Completeness.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake I don't think using "jump" instead of goto gets us to the point where we can define a sufficient and necessary set of operation. It's probably true that every language would need some sort of jump operation (and if it's only function calls), but I don't think you'll be able to come up with further operations to make it sufficient. For example the lambda calculus has two operations: application (i.e. our jump operation) and abstraction (i.e. creating functions)...

Comment: ...I don't see a way to (non-meaninglessly) define a type of operation, such that the lambda calculus' abstraction operation fits that definition, any Turing complete language has an operation fitting that definition, and any language that has an operation fitting that definition is Turing complete.

Comment: I'm still bugged by the wikipedia [Turing completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) article stating: <blockquote>at a minimum, conditional branching (e.g., an "if" and "goto" statement) and the ability to change arbitrary memory locations (e.g., having variables)</blockquote>

Comment: @JoshuaDrake I don't think the article is trying to claim that any Turing-complete language needs to have those operations. Especially since it specifically restricts that statement to procedural languages. Except for a form of goto (i.e. function application) the Lambda Calculus doesn't have any of those things. I think "minimum" here only means that in a language that only has those features, you can't remove any of them without losing Turing completeness. Not that there's no other minimal set of operations that is also sufficient for Turing completeness.

Comment: I believe I see your point now.  Given that any language must prove itself [Turing Complete](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TuringComplete) there is no reasonable way to say: If you do only X you will create a [Turing Equivalent](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TuringEquivalent) language. Thank you.

Comment: In practical terms, where function calls and `while` loops are supported at the language level they're implemented by using a `jump` or `goto` instruction at the machine-code level (whether or not the language _exposes_ direct control of that instruction to the programmer).  Thus you might view `goto` as the prerequisite command, where `while` and function calls are simply programmer-friendly abstractions of `goto`.  Basically, Turing-completeness requires a 'jump' operation, and it makes no difference how that operation gets packaged.

Comment: @aroth I believe that was already mentioned in this comment chain somewhere, but while some sort of jump instruction is required for the language to be Turing complete, that is not sufficient on its own. Also if we're talking about the machine-code level, on many architectures function calls and returns have their own instructions that can't be replaced with a jump (because there's no direct access to the PC register), so gotos and function calls do not and can not compile to the same instruction on those architectures.

Answer (score 19):

There are various single instructions that lead to Turing complete languages. The typical example is "subtract and branch if zero". These are well known in the context of assembly language programming. See [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer) for details.

This leads to a characterization: a language is Turing complete if and only if it is able to simulate the operations of fetching and storing integers in memory and performing the "subtract and branch if zero" operation on them.

Answer (score 18):

This isn't a general answer to your question, but by the [structured programming theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_program_theorem), all that is needed is the ability to do selection (e.g., `if` in C/C++) and repetition (e.g., `while` in C/C++). *Edit: as pointed out by Dave Clarke in the comments, the structured programming theorem also requires sequence. I didn't initially list this since I took for granted the reader would understand that basic blocks of other instructions, such as those alluded to later for reading from and writing to the memory store, etc., were also necessary). It is, of course, better to be explicit; you need to be able to do these things, too.*

Since both of these can be implemented using a conditional jump instruction (e.g., `JNZ` in x86), that is also sufficient for Turing-equivalence.

Note that other things are required, i.e., the ability to write an unbounded number of symbols (e.g., bits... 0 or 1) to some sort of external memory store. In that sense, real computers are not Turing equivalent, since none of them have an infinite amount of storage. The Turing model is still useful, though, since the amount of memory is typically huge, and even though any problem a real computer can solve can be solved by a deterministic finite automaton, using that model of computation isn't particularly useful (since the number of states would be preposterously huge).

Note that this isn't necessarily at odds with sepp2k's answer; this is sort of just a different way to think about the same question.

EDIT:

Note also that you don't really need both `if` and `while` in C/C++. You can simulate `if` using `while` as follows:

```
bool C;
// some code that sets C
if(C) { /* some other code /* }
// rest of the program
```

The following code is always equivalent:

```
bool C;
// some code that sets C
bool C2 = C;
while(C2) { /* some other code /* C2 = false; }
// rest of the program
```

Well... the construction should work and be possible if you're careful, that is. Note also that if you have recursive functions, you eventually need selection also; since recursive functions without selection can't really implement base cases, so any recursive function would result in infinite recursion.

EDIT:

Also, regarding your question as to whether the ability to write a program that doesn't halt is sufficient for Turing equivalence, the answer is no; it is necessary, but not sufficient. We can solve the halting problem for programs written in a language which cannot express programs that fail to halt; the answer is "the program does halt" for all instances. However, we can define a language where the only instruction causes the machine to enter an infinite loop... such a language isn't Turing-equivalent.

Answer (score 17):

The combinators $\mathbf{S}$ and $\mathbf{K}$ where, $(\mathbf{S}\ x\ y\ z) = (x\ z\ (y\ z))$ and $(\mathbf{K}\ x\ y) = x$ are sufficient to express any (closed) lambda term, therefore any computable function.  See this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Completeness_of_the_S-K_basis) for details.

In fact, the lambda term $\mathbf{X}=\lambda x.((x\ \mathbf{S})\ \mathbf{K})$ is a sufficient  basis to express all lambda terms. See later in the same [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#One-point_basis).

Answer (score 7):

### The language constructs are interchangeable

There is no set minimum criteria about what constructs must ***natively*** be provided by a programming language.  If it provides some weird constructs that can somehow be convoluted to express a Turing-complete system, then apparently those constructs are "just as suitable" as any others.

To prove this - a language that provides *only* a "subtract and branch if zero" operation is Turing complete; there exist Turing complete languages that don't provide a separate "substract and branch if zero" construct, ergo there is no construct or a set of constructs that is mandatory.

The effects of any TP-complete language construct can be emulated by the constructs of any other TP-complete language.