# What language features would I need to remove from a real programming language to make it decidable?

Tags: computability, programming-languages, undecidability, halting-problem, turing-completeness

Let's say that I want to restrict certain features of a common programming language--for instance, C--such that the result is decidable, and thus no longer Turing-complete.  **What language features, at minimum, would I need to remove to make a given programming language decidable?**

For the purpose of this question, let's assume the following:

- The original language in question is imperative.
- We're not restricting memory in any meaningful way.
- The result isn't hideously crippled (e.g. no subsets of C that only consist of `printf` calls).

Comment: The question isn't well-defined: the subset of languages features to remove is not unique (there are probably many subsets you could remove to make the resulting language decidable).  Also, it's not clear to me what "not restricting memory" means precisely, nor what counts as "hideously crippled".

Comment: Arguably, taking a Turing-complete language and removing features until termination becomes decidable _is_ hideously crippling it! Actually, I wrote "until termination becomes undecidable" but it's not clear from your question what property you want to be decidable.

Comment: Partial duplicate: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19591/what-makes-prolog-turing-complete, something else that's worth lookup up is "total functional programming". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_functional_programming. Epigram, Charity, and Coq are examples of languages where every program either terminates or coterminates.

Comment: The way you phrase your question, it's very illposed -- most programming languages *are* decidable! Note that in formal languages, "decidable" means that you can decide membership; that's a task every compiler performs. Why do you tag [tag:halting-problem]?

Comment: @Raphael OP is asking about the computations performed by the programs, not about whether well-formedness is decidable. As a language, any programming language itself is assumed to be decidable!

Comment: @BrianO I don't see any phrasing that support your interpretation. (Regarding "every programming language is decidable", I have [bad news](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/9196/1546) for you.)