# Are if statements unnecessary if a program is represented as an explicit state machine?

Tags: programming-languages, computation-models

This question occurred to me some time ago when I was thinking about whether or not `if` statements are fundamental in computation.

Consider a program that manages a single bank account (for the sake of simplicity). The bank account could be defined as something like

```
Account 
{
    int balance; // current amount of Money

    boolean withdraw(int n)
    {
       if (balance >= n)
       {
           balance = balance -n;
           return true;
       }
       else
           return false;
    }

    void deposit(int n)
    {
       amount = amount + n;
    }
}
```

Since the program has no way to known in which state it currently is unless it performs validations using `if` statements, as in the withdraw operation, `if` statements are unavoidable.

However, over the course of time, the program will pass through a finite set of states that can be known beforehand. In this particular case, a state is defined solely by the value of the `balance` variable, hence we would have states: `{balance = 0 , balance = 1, balance = 2...}`.

If we assign each state a number, say state {0,1,2,....} with a 1-1 correspondence to the above set of states, and assign to each operation a number identifier as well (say `deposit = 0 and withdraw = 1`), we could model the program as an explicit transition between states and therefore remove every `if` statement from the code.

Consider that `state = 0` is the state where `balance = 0` and we want to perform a deposit of 50 dollars, if we coded every single possible execution of the deposit function, we could just define the deposit function as

```
void deposit (int n)
{
   deposit[state][n]; // índex deposit instance for state = 0, amount = n;
}
```

`deposit[][]` would be a matrix of pointers for a set of functions that represent each possible execution of deposit, like

```
deposit[0][0] -> balance = balance + 0; state = 0;
deposit[0][1] -> balance = balance + 1; state = 1;

....
```

In the case of withdrawal, it would be like:

```
boolean withdraw (int n)
{
    // índex withdraw instance for the current state and amount=n
    return withdraw[state][n]; 
}
```

`withdraw[][]` would be a matrix of pointers for a set of functions that represent each possible execution of withdraw, like:

```
deposit[0][100] -> return false; state = state;
...
deposit[200][100] -> balance = balance - 100; return true; state = 100;
```

In this situation, the program the managers the single bank account can be written without using a single `if` statement!

As a consequence however, we have to use A LOT more memory, which may make the solution unreasonable. Also one may put the question of how did we fill the `deposit[][]` and `withdraw[][]` matrices? By hand? It somehow implies that a previous computation that used `if`s as necessary to determine and possible states and transitions.

All in all, are `if`s fundamental or does my example prove that they aren't? If they are, can you provide me an example where this does not work? If they are not, why dont we use solutions like these more often?

Is there some law of computation which states that `if` statements are unavoidable?

Comment: So, you want an array of functions instead of condition statements? Why don't I like this?

Comment: Why did you post this twice? You just completely wasted my time when I wrote an answer to your question and then found it had already been answered.

Comment: See also [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/991/are-there-minimum-criteria-for-a-programming-language-being-turing-complete/995#995).

Answer (score 4):

Literal `if` statements are not fundamental. As you've shown, it's possible to remove them by writing your program as a state machine, though at the gigantic cost of having to have a different version of the `widthdraw()` function for every possible starting balance and withdrawal amount. You can also avoid literal `if` statements by replacing

```
if (condition) {
    foo
} else {
    bar
}
```

with

```
b1 := condition
b2 := not(b1)
while (b1) {
    foo
    b1 := false
}
while (b2) {
    bar
    b2 := false
}
```

On the other hand, doing so has no clear advantages and many disadvantages. The gigantic-table-of-functions approach leads to huge redundancy, is very hard to maintain and is very hard for compilers and CPUs to optimize.  If you're lucky, the `while` loop hack might compile to the same code as the simple code with `if` statements but it's much harder to read and much more prone to programmers mistakenly thinking they can optimize it.

At a fundamental level, some form of conditional execution is necessary. If you have no kind of conditional statement at all, then you can only perform a class of very limited programs called "straight-line programs". These are, perhaps surprisingly, useful as a model of computation because they have a fairly simple correspondence with circuits: they correspond to the simplest notion of algorithm, i.e., take your input data and perform a fixed sequence of operations on it. For example, when you compute the length of a 2D vector, you're using a straight-line program: square the $x$-coordinate, square the $y$-coordinate, add the two squares, take the square root (at least, assuming that all those arithmetic operations, including square root, are taken as being built in to your langauge).

Comment: Exercise to the reader: find the "conditional" in $\mu$-calculus.

Answer (score 2):

Your construction seems a bit tautological. The if statement is itself
a form or branching through an array of two addresses, depending on a
value that is 0 or 1. Actually, the if statement generalizes to the
case statement, which may be implemented as branching through an
array. Whether the array is code or static data is immaterial and
pretty much in the eyes of the beholder.

Another way to state this is that **your program could be simulated by a
Turing machine, which does not have any if statement, and could thus be a positive answer to your question**.

Indeed, a Turing machine should be as good an answer as any other state machine. Compared to a FSA, the only difference is that it can read and write on an infinite tape.

So, if you do not accept the Turing machine as an answer, I wonder whether your problem is not more with eliminating
this infinite memory tape, at the expense of replacing it with an
infinite program (TM states and transitions).

Then, I am afraid you may just fall into something similar
to a [Turing Tar Pit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_tarpit), or much worse (a Turing hell?).

The main point is that the technique you are proposing will require
your program to have an infinite size, if it is to be equivalent to
the original program, using infinite matrices, i.e. really an infinite
number of states.

You might not worrry about it, considering that we already work as if
we could use unbounded integer in memory. That is true, but we use
integer in a very precise way, that is finitely described. As a
consequence, it is perfectly possible to mimic computation with
arbitrary long integer, and it is actually done in some systems.

One fundamental principle of computer science (and I would add
mathematics, but that has to be made precise) is that everything must
be finitely definable.

To make any sense, your infinite program would similarly have to
follow a finite specification, where your if statement would be back,
or the TM with its infinite tape.

If you forget this constraint, then you drastically change the domain
of discourse, as you get a continuous (rather than denumerable) infinity
of different programs. You are no longer talking of computability with
its accepted meaning, and its physical realizability. Actually, I
suspect that you can then no longer consider a concept that would
ressemble computability (but that is a somewhat fuzzy statement).

Answer (score 2):

On a processor, the if-else statement is ultimately a conditional branching instruction, where the execution address is generated on the basis of some comparison to get to a decision.

On hardware (like on an FPGA) however, if-else is (for example) done using a multiplexer/demultiplexer where the 'condition' is done through the state of the 'select' inputs. In this case, the logic for which branching logic is burned onto hardware, where there's no need for a "next address" generator.

If I understand correctly, your question is whether branching on-the-fly is "fundamental" to computing, or whether it can be circumvented by other ways.

I would say that, yes it is fundamental to computing. On the FPGA, the branch states are usually finite at the level of one mux/demux, therefore, there's no physical analogue to branching. On a processor, however, given the practical limits on memory, condition branching is a fundamental operation.

Comment: Welcome to CS Stack Exchange! This answer explains why conditional instructions are necessary in practice on processor-based systems but note that there are models of computation such as automata that don't really have a processor (but which still have some kind of conditional).

Answer (score 0):

In a way, if statements are unavoidable at some stage, unless you write things "by hand", but in that case, it is not at all clear that you don't preform branching operations in your brain, so let's leave that aside.

Consider a program P in assembler (to have a low common ground). In assembler, the only branching operation is "if x>0 goto l1, else goto l2"

So assume you have a program without those. Then, you can define for every line $l$ in the code, a unique line $l'$ that always follows $l$ in the execution. Thus, the program either gets to exit and terminates within $n$ commands ($n$ being the number of lines) or it runs forever.

From this, we learn that if you want to describe a big system, but you want to describe it without branching, then you will need to write it more or less explicitly. If you use branching, you can get things exponentially more efficient.

Also, your question is related to the concept of [symbolic representation and symbolic algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_computation) which can affect the succinctness of representation.

Answer (score 0):

*This is really answering Devian Dover's last question on this theme:
**[Where does the need for conditionals (if, switch, jump tables, etc…) truly arise?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33093/where-does-the-need-for-conditionals-if-switch-jump-tables-etc-truly-ari)** Since that last question was closed as duplicate to the one I am answering
here, I guess it is OK to answer it here. This answer is thus quite
different from my previous one here, since the two questions are related rather than duplicates.*

[Hoopje's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33093/where-does-the-need-for-conditionals-if-switch-jump-tables-etc-truly-ari/33103#33103) shows that Lambda Calculus can create
conditionals out of its elementary constructs. Whether they are
actually more elementary than conditional is a subjective matter.
If you Had a `while` loop plus `exit` statement, that would also let you
do conditionals, though a `while` loop may be seen as more complex
than a conditional.

Another example is the [Post Correspondence Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem) (PCP). It can
simulate a Turing machine, though it does not even have a concept of
execution or evaluation to start with, let alone a conditional.

To take a more amusing example, you can [build Turing Machines with
Lego bricks](http://www.legoturingmachine.org/), but there is no Lego brick that identifies as an `if`
statement.

What you are really asking is an [ontological](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology) question, and such
questions often have only subjective answers. What organization there is
to the world is largely made up by your own individual or collective
subjective reconstruction of world order. The fact that the universe
is organized and structured is not to be denied, but the
expression of this structure by laws, the concepts we may put forward
as fundamental, may vary without actually changing the structures
described.

To formulate it in a more formal way, different systems of axioms
could characterize a given unique set of possible interpretations.

You are asking:

> My point is, where do conditionals come from? Where do they stop? Can we avoid them somehow? Can you prove me we need them? If we do, why do we put them at the hardware level? Why does the input of a program have to be compared against values to determine the branch to execute?

So my answer to your quest, rather than your question, is that conditional
are one convenient way to express some algorithm is some formalization
of what a computation may be. They stop where you
choose to make them stop. We can avoid them, and many other concepts,
since computation and algorithms can be expressed by totally different
means. We do not need them: they happen to be, when we want to look
at them, but we can proceed by other means when we do not (want to)
see them. We do not have to put them at the hardware level since we do
not have to have them at all. We do not have to compare input to
anything since computation can be express by other means.

A very negative answer. The point is that the use of conditionals
corresponds to a specific model of computation, essentially the [von
Neumann machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture), that has been considered convenient as a fundamental
set of concepts to represent computation in physical devices. In a
sense, it is pure expediency. It is just one way, among many others,
to see the structure and order of the computational world, one that we
find easy enough to deal with, and for which we can produce physical
simulators (called computers) that are not too expensive to produce or
to use.

Conditionals are just one of many way we have to apprehend and express assessment of
change or diversity.