# Do we need recursion in programming language to solve any problem?

Tags: computability, programming-languages, computation-models, turing-completeness

My question is simple: If we want to be able to solve **every problem, that we can solve using recursions**, do we need programming language to allow us use recursions?

Assuming we are allowed to use: conditional evaluation of blocks (if/else), cycles(for,while), dynamic allocation of memory.

I know, that we won't be able to implement everything the way we want. However, I'm asking whether we are able to solve everything, just by using different implementation - or by modification of algorithm to be non-recursive.

Comment: [Closely related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/991/are-there-minimum-criteria-for-a-programming-language-being-turing-complete), maybe even a duplicate.

Comment: @Raphael Yea, closely related, but not a duplicate. However, as I now see. The answer for my question is, to check turing completeness, and then I need to search for criteria.

Comment: @Raphael I do not understand your understanding of "*any problem*". To me the meaning is the same as "*every problem*" in this context. I had not seen your comment, and was at loss to interpret the edit by Miro (as seen in my answer). But I am not a native speaker either (who is, given the number of English dialects? **:)**

Comment: @Miro What is your intent in adding "*that we can solve using recursions*" to your question. I tried to answer that, but I fail to see what it is supposed to change.

Comment: @babou Every means every, and there are unsolvable problems even when using recursion, ie. halting problem.

Comment: @Raphael It seems to me that the closely related question was a pretty bad one. There is an infinity of different criteria to ensure Turing power. Indeed we know that very different programming languages, with completely different features, all have Turing power. Actually, in early times, people would design programming languages corresponding to formal mathematical models, See Lisp, Snobol, APL, Prolog, Algol, Setl. And they did not go as far as they could have. See also Turing complete weirdos such as Intercal, Brainfuck and other [esoteric programming languages](https://esolangs.org/)..

Comment: @babou I think the question after minimal computational models is valid and interesting. Of course, we would not want to use such in practice, but it's important for understanding where computational power "comes from". (cf the very confused question we had a while ago about programming without `if`) But let's not discuss this here.

Comment: @Raphael I agree that these issues of minimality are essential (even outside spanning-trees :). But the question as stated called for a zillion answers. And most students know of Chyurch Turing thesis and the multiplicity of models of computation. Miro's question is better focussed.

Comment: @babou It's still rather boring since the answer is clearly "no" (and every undergrad learns that much); well, it *is* an exciting result but not one that is hard to find or understand, a posteriori. In particular, the answers to that other question say as much, which is what "duplicate" typically means on SE (not "literally the same question", but "your answer is over there").

Comment: @Raphael Boring, I think not? Check: I am fascinated by the way the OP
accepted the only wrong answer, which got more votes as a result. Then
user swick remarked it was wrong, since one loop is needed. The author
of the answer swept it under the rug, as being achieved by a specific
assignment ... This kind of assignment does have a name in
programming: **goto**, and it can indeed be used to create loops.  But
explaining in an accepted answer that (1) loop is not needed, and (2)
because it can be replaced by a goto, seems to be adding insult to
injury. Did Miro notice answers incompatibilities?

Comment: @babou Yep. I overlooked that. However, I didn't accepted his answer, because of votes, but before you have written an answer. And the edit I made to the question, didn't change your answer, you didn't need to edit it.

Comment: I did not say you accepted because of the votes, difference was
weak. But accepted answers, or already upvoted ones, tend to attract
votes, independently of quality. My interest in SE is also observing
social phenomena. The answer you chose had otherwise many interesting
side-remarks. But you cannot get Turing power without infinity hidden
somewhere (sometimes well hidden). The loop gives you
infinity. Without infinity, all programs terminate, as in primitive
recursive functions, that use only finite recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need recursion, and as you suggest, and as confirmed by
[Dave Clarke's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41404/do-we-need-recursion-in-programming-language-to-solve-any-problem/41406#41406), you only need conditionals, loops and memory
allocation and assignment.

You can use it to simulate recursion. Or more simply you can use it to
implement arbitrary Turing machines. Just do it for a universal TM, so
you get to implement only one :)

You can actually almost also do it without loops, but not quite. **You
need at least one loop** if you expect to have infinite computations,
which is implied by Turing power.

However, it could be an implicit loop that loops back to the beginning
of the program, unless you execute a termination statement.

You can remark that control of a Turing Machine has exactly that: a
single loop applied to a case statement, looking up a transition
table.

If you wonder how abitrary many loops can be encoded into a single loop, is
is very similar to dovetailing techniques use to explore space
according to several indices. Think of indexing all pairs  of
natural numbers, with or without upperbounds, with a single integer.

**Added after the question was modified:**

If you consider "*every problem, that we can solve using recursions*",
rather than "*any problem*", you do not change the question, unless you
are a lot more precise (and restrictive) about what else is available,
and what use of recursion you allow.

But an unrestricted recursion will give you at least one unlimited
loop, which is usually enough to get Turing Power, if you allow
unlimited memory allocation.

Note that there are limited uses of recursion that keep you below
Turing Power, in precise settings. Look for example at [primitive
recursive functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function).

<sub>I understand from your later comment that you made that change, so as to limit the request for solvability to what was already solvable, thus excluding such problems as the halting problem. If that is the intent, it is of course better stated. But, I guess, everyone had instinctively understood it that way, and the change was disconcerting (at least for me).</sub>

Comment: First time I see [Turing Power](http://cdn.meme.am/instances2/500x/2609846.jpg)

Answer (score 8):

In short, to answer your questions:

(1) You can convert any recursive algorithm into its non-recursive form.

(2) As stated by the others, you have all the features you need.

### Computational Power (Turing-completeness)

You probably know that you cannot solve **any** problem, for instance, the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) is *undecidable*. And so are many other problems, such as deciding whether an arbitrary formula in first order logic is provable. Thus, with today's knowledge on computability, even the most advanced computer/programming system imaginable won't be able to process every query even if all the data is available.

When assessing the computational power of languages, computer scientists often use the notion of **Turing-completeness**: 
If you can describe (and run) any Turing machine in your programming language, then it is Turing complete and can solve any problem which can be solved by a Turing machine.

To get a feel for Turing machines, I strongly encourage you to use a [Simulator](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html) and try to solve some simple problems.

In particular, have a look at the syntax of the sample program in the Simulator, which should give you an idea of your minimal language.

### Expressive Power and Minimality

When it comes to language design, expressive power is more important to me than the ability to solve any computable problem. Many useful domain-specific languages are not Turing-complete, but address specific problems very well.

However, equally powerful computational models such as the Lambda Calculus (functional programming) or the Pi Calculus (concurrent programming) show that you can have a very small set of elegant, composable language elements to construct larger systems, to be able to *reason* about their composition while having the computational power of Turing machines at the same time. Beautiful.

So if it is minimality you are looking for, take a closer look at the Lambda Calculus. 
Other noteworthy well designed minimal languages are:

- LISP
- Prolog
- Smalltalk and in particular Self

Feel free to add more languages to your personal list (and please let me know ;)

Comment: Well, it's more than an answer. I feel like at "automation and grammars" classes, but you're right. I just needed to check for turing-completeness.

Comment: What do you mean by not even needing loops? You do need loops *or* recursion to be Turing complete. Or does "writing memory" mean something weird, like changing the code of the program while it's executing?

Comment: svick: You are of course right. Indeed, what I meant is that you could change the machine state (the instruction pointer, or rather the 'follow up state') by writing to a particular memory address. But yeah, that's really weird :)

Comment: Miro: Sorry, I couldn't restrain myself, I find language design exciting and I got carried away. Thanks for accepting my answer :)

Comment: Just one thing I had overlooked. We need loops. However, it doesn't have to be `for`, `while`. It could be just loop made using `goto`. So, your (2) statement is not correct :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. What I meant is that you do need high-level loop constructs and that writing the next program state to memory is sufficient. But I see that my wording is misleading, I changed my answer. Sorry for causing confusion :(

Answer (score 3):

If you have all the features you mention, you don't need recursion.

Using dynamic memory you can implement a stack. This can be used to save "partial computations" and the while loop can loop through them, thereby mimicking recursion.

But just because you can do it, doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: "But just because you can do it, doesn't mean it's a good idea." - This is what is it all about... people can use recursion, so together with virtual methods they often make chaotic software(just for simple problems), that is often hard to analyze and reason about,... making software "bottom-up / no recursions" requires developers to write clear code, that is easily understandable, because you don't have to study tons of functions and classes that use each other, like a spaghetti code - hard to make parallel, and distribute computation

Comment: Write a function that adds up the numbers stored in the leaves of a binary tree with and without recursion. See the difference recursion can make.

Comment: Non-recursive is easy too. Make stack, push root node. While stack is not empty: pop&store top, if top has children, add children to stack, else add number to sum... Few lines.

Comment: Hardly as transparent as the recursive version. But ultimately it's a question of taste.

Comment: Miro: I encourage you to read [Why Functional Programming Matters](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dat/miranda/whyfp90.pdf) by John Hughes.

Comment: I hope people don't write software as described in comment #3. To process recursive structures one should have a strong tendency towards using recursive algorithms. Otherwise its like using a hammer to insert a screw: It might work, but its still the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score -1):

To complete others' answers, I think you might want to check the difference between a recursive process, and a recursive procedure. A recursive procedure doesn't necessarily execute a recursive process. When Babou writes that you can do everything without loops, he is probably secretly thinking about recursive procedures yielding iterative processes.

Comment: Downvoters, care to explain?