# Does a do-while loop suffice for Turing-completeness?

Tags: programming-languages, turing-completeness, loops, imperative-programming

I know that, in imperative programming languages, a while-do loop is sufficient as a control flow construct to make the language Turing-complete (as far as control flow goes - of course we also need unbounded memory and certain operators...). The gist of my question is: does a do-while loop have the same computational power as a while-do loop? In other words, can a language be Turing-complete if it's impossible to skip instructions entirely.

I realise that some of the semantics here could be a bit ambiguous, so let me phrase the actual question with a specific example:

[Brainfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck) (BF) is a Turing tarpit where the only control flow is a while-do loop, denoted as `[...]` (there is a complete language spec at the bottom of the question, in case you're not familiar with Brainfuck). Let's define a new language BF*, where `,.+-<>` have the same semantics as in BF, but instead of `[]` we have `{}` which denotes a do-while loop. That is, the only difference to BF is that every loop is executed at least once before further iterations can be skipped.

**Is BF* Turing-complete?** If it is, I'd be interested in how I could translate BF to BF*. If it isn't, how do I prove that?

Some observations of my own:

- Not every BF program can be translated into BF*. For instance, it's impossible to write a program in BF* which may or may not read or print a value - if the program potentially prints one or more values, it will always print at least one. However, there might be a Turing-complete subset of BF which can be translated to BF*.
- We cannot simply translate `[f]` (where `f` is some arbitrary, Brainfuck program consisting only of `+-[]<>`) to `f-1{f}` (in an attempt to cancel the effect of the first iteration), because a) [not every computable function has a computable inverse](https://mathoverflow.net/a/68358/56581) and b) even if it did, `f-1` wouldn't necessarily have fewer loops than `f` so applying this step recursively isn't guaranteed to terminate in the first place.

---

Here is a quick overview over the Brainfuck language. Brainfuck operates on an infinite tape where each cell contains a byte values, initially zero. Overflows wrap around, so incrementing 255 gives 0 and vice versa. The language consists of 8 instructions:

```
+   Increment the current cell.
-   Decrement the current cell.
>   Move tape head to the right.
<   Move tape head to the left.
,   Input a character from STDIN into the current cell.
.   Output the current cell as a character to STDOUT.
[   If the current cell is zero, jump past the matching ].
]   If the current cell is non-zero, jump back to just behind the matching [.
```

Comment: [Very similar question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/991/are-there-minimum-criteria-for-a-programming-language-being-turing-complete).

Comment: interesting but think it is not fully carefully constructed. `[]` is not exactly defining a "while do" loop in BF. as in your table the left and right brackets evaluate the current cell zero/ nonzero. so what is the exact description of the corresponding `{}` braces evaluation logic? suggest further dialog/ discussion in [chat]. also your "observations" are more like "postulates" or "propositions" without proof.

Comment: @vzn Those are good points. I figured that the obvious definition of `{}` would be to make `{` do nothing at all and `}` the same as `]`. I won't have much time over the next few days, but I'll join you in chat when I do find some time.

Comment: so alas this is apparently somewhat subtle to ask and there seem to be two totally different questions here. (1) given any Turing complete language with a while-do loop (and "other stuff"), can it be converted to a Turing complete language with only a do-while loop instead. but then one needs to know more about the "other stuff" in detail to answer. (2) given BF and a new BF* with given definition of `{}` and taking away `[]`, is BF* Turing complete. with the understanding that BF `[]` is a construct _only something somewhat like/ analogous to_ a while-do loop in Turing complete languages.

Comment: @vzn part (1) was only the TL;DR part of my question. I'm fully aware that this is probably impossible to answer for "some language". This is why I've phrased the actual question in terms of a very simple toy language (BF) to really narrow it down to the behaviour of the loops (because I figured *if* BF* can be shown to be TC that would make it simpler to show it for other languages which only have do-while loops). I'm not sure how you think BF loops are different from other language's while-do loops though.

Comment: BF is intentionally strongly unlike standard programming/ computing languages. think it would be easier to answer (as in DRs' below) by picking a standard programming language. maybe another question? think the two questions are much different and not necessarily related.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know Brainfuck so you'll have to do some translation from my pseudocode.  But, assuming that Brainfuck behaves sensibly (ha!), everything below should apply.

do-while is equivalent to while-do.  `do X while Y` is equivalent to `X; while Y do X` and, assuming you have conditionals, `while Y do X` is equivalent to `if Y then (do X while Y)`.

Life is a bit harder if you don't have conditionals.  If you have while-do, you can simulate `if Y then X` using something like this:

```
B := true
while (Y and B) do
    X
    B := false
endwhile
```

But what if you only have do-while?  I claim that the following simulates `if Y then X`, assuming that `X` terminates given the current value of the variables.  (This isn't guaranteed: the program `if y=0 then loopforever` terminates if `y != 0`, even though `X` loops for any value of the variables).  Let `V1`, ..., `Vn` be the variables modified by `X` and let `X'` be `X` modified so that it uses `Vi'` instead of `Vi` for each of those variables. `swap(A,B)` denotes the obvious code that swaps the variables `A` and `B`.

```
V1' := V1; ...; Vn' := Vn
V1'' := V1; ...; Vn'' := Vn
C := 0
do
    X'
    swap (V1',V1''); ...; swap (Vn',Vn'')
    C := C+1
while Y and C<2
V1 := V1'; ...; Vn := Vn'
```

The idea is the following. First, suppose that `Y` is false.  We simulate doing `X` once, and store the results in `V1''`, ..., `Vn''`; `V1'`, ..., `Vn'` hold the original values of `V1`, ..., `Vn`. Then, we assign `V1 := V1'; ...; Vn := Vn'`, which does nothing. So, if `Y` is false, we've done nothing.  Now, suppose that `Y` is true.  We'll now simulate `X` *twice*, storing the results in both the "primed" and "double-primed" variables. So, now, the assignments at the end of the loop have the effect that `X` was computed once. Note that `Y` only depends on the "unprimed" variables, so its value is not affected by running the loop repeatedly.

OK, so what if `X` might not terminate for the current value of the variables? (Thanks to Martin Ender for pointing out this possibility.)
In that case, we need to simulate `X` instruction-by-instruction, using similar ideas to those above. Each instruction definitely terminates so we can use the `if` simulation above to do instruction decoding, along the lines of "If the opcode is foo, do this; if it's bar, do that; ...". So, now, we use a loop to iterate through the instructions of `X`, using an instruction pointer and so on so that we know which instruction to execute next. At the end of each iteration of the loop, check `Y` and check whether `X` has halted yet. If `Y` is false, the swapping technique allows us to undo the effects of `X`'s first instruction.

Comment: This is a neat idea, but I think there is one issue here: consider the case where `Y` is false but `X` doesn't terminate on the current set of variable values. `if Y then X` terminates, but your translation doesn't, because it always needs to execute `X'` at least once.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Urgh. You're right. So we need to use the loop to simulate `X` instruction-by-instruction and check `Y` after each instruction. Each instruction is guaranteed to terminate so everything will work. But it's a pain to write down.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if it's possible to deconstruct `X` like that if it starts with a while loop/conditional itself. I'll have to think about this some more.

Comment: Also "So, now, we use a loop to iterate through the instructions of X, using an instruction pointer and so on so that we know which instruction to execute next." I feel like this in itself might require a conditional of some sort.

Comment: In fact, if we can execute arbitrary code `X` instruction by instruction, we have written an interpreter for a Turing-complete language which itself obviously requires Turing-completeness.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes, writing an interpreter requires conditionals. But, since each instruction terminates, we can use the conditional construction that I demonstrated explicitly in the answer. So, we have written (or, at least, provided a detailed sketch of) an interpreter for a Turing-complete language, which *shows* Turing-completeness of the thing we wrote the interpreter in.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure how you define "each instruction" if `X'` is non-linear. Would you mind including some more detail for a simple but non-trivial toy `X`? E.g. `do (while A do B) while C`? (the outer `do while` comes from the outer `while do` that we're currently translating)