# Can a 1-tape turing machine simulate a stack?

Tags: turing-machines, computation-models, stacks

Is it possible to simulate a stack-based machine using a 1-tape turing machine? I cannot wrap my head around it as turing machines do not provide mechanisms such as pointers.

I failed to find any examples or explanations. If it is possible, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Machines that have *only* a stack are called *pushdown automata*. They are less powerful than Turing machine, so yes: TMs can simulate stacks.

Turing machines are a fairly simplistic model of computation, which can make programming in them hard. Try to start with simple things; for instance, implement a counter. If you feel ambitious, try implementing the [basic building blocks](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/995/98) of (Turing-complete) imperative programming as Turing machines. This should convince you, then, that TMs *are* as powerful as any other¹ model.

As for your question, you don't need pointers for a stack. TM tapes have a *direction*, and you can easily label cells by introducing special alphabet symbols; the TM can then move over the tape and look for these labels. It's all a matter of encoding.

---

1. Ignoring hyper-computation.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what @Raphael said, it's very easy to actually do it.  Just make a rule for your Turing Machine that every time it moves left, it will also write null.  *Voilà!*  You have made a Pushdown Automata.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually need to design a simulation for a machine supporting both a stack and registers.

Comment: @just.kidding Building a simulator for "modern" machine architectures is definitely possible, but not very interesting (by my estimation).