# Is McCarthy Formalism first ever formalism for defining functions recursively in computer science?

Tags: computability, recursion, history, lisp

McCarthy formalism is a formalism for defining functions recursively, first introduced in classic paper *Recursive Functions of Symbolic Expressions and Their Computation by Machine, Part I* (1960).

From Wikipedia:

> In his 1967 *Computation: Finite and Infinite Machines*, Marvin Minsky
>   in his *§ 10.6 Conditional Expressions: The McCarthy Formalism*
>   describes the "formalism" as follows:
>
> "Practical computer languages do not lend themselves to formal
>   mathematical treatment--they are not designed to make it easy to prove
>   theorems about the procedures they describe. In a paper by McCarthy
>   [1963] we find a formalism that enhances the practical aspect of the
>   recursive-function concept, while preserving and improving its
>   mathematical clarity.
>
> McCarthy introduces "conditional expressions"
>   of the form
>   `f = (if p1 then e1 else e2)` where the `ei` are expressions
>   and `p1` is a statement (or equation) that may be true or false. This
>   expression means: *See if `p1` is true; if so the value of `f` is given by
>   `e1`. IF `p1` is false, the value of `f` is given by `e2`. [...]*
>
> The McCarthy formalism is like the general recursive (Kleene) system,
>   in being based on some basic functions, composition, and equality, but
>   with the conditional expression alone replacing both the
>   primitive-recursive scheme and the minimization operator." (Minsky
>   1967:192-193)

I'm interested in chronology. Was there any other formalism regarding recursive function before McCarthy Formalism (in computer science)?

Comment: Such as Gödel's formalism for general recursive functins which predates McCarthy by at least 25 years?

Comment: Sure, but that's mathematics. I'm asking specifically about computer science.

Comment: @Siegmeyer In TCS, there is no meaningful difference. $\mu$-recursion and $\lambda$-calculus are mathematical models we use in computer science. See also [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/991/98).

Comment: FWIW, [formal semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) seem to have emerged later. Is that the field you are referring to, as opposed to computability/recursion theory?

Comment: @Siegmeyer Computer Science is a branch of mathematics.

Comment: @Siegmeyer: Wehre do you think people like McCarthy got their ideas from? They were very knowledgable, also about mathematics.