# Compiling an impure language into a pure stack-based language

Tags: programming-languages, logic, functional-programming

For a personal learning and fun project, I build an abstract virtual machine based on a stack. The instructions are simple and act on the top of the stack only. There are also stack operators such as `SWAP`, `DUP` or `ROT`. I have no way to manage memory, pointers, or variables (it's all on the stack after all). Typically, here is a very simple example:

```
square:
    DUP           -- duplicate the top of the stack
    MUL           -- consumes the first two values at the top of the stack and pushes the product
    RET           -- come back after the last call of `square`.

main:
    PUSH 6        -- pushes `6` on the stack
    CALL square   -- call the label `square`
```

Such a VM and IR can be related to a [concatenative language](https://concatenative.org/wiki/view/Concatenative%20language), which offers the interesting feature of quotations; so this program "becomes" the following:

```
square == dup mul
main   == 6 square
```

My question is to what extent this type of VM (and therefore more broadly simple concatenative languages) is limited (or not). Without any use of FFI, I wonder if impure languages can be fully compiled into it, and if so, how?

For example, with a naive and trivial compilation, is the following C-like program compilable in a pure concatenative approach?

```
void assign_and_double(int *dest_ptr, int src)
{
    *dest_ptr = src * 2;
}
```

I had imagined a somewhat ridiculous approach that would simulate pointers with quotations: the quotation would represent the address, and the data would be in the quotation, for the example given just above, one could imagine this:

```
assign_and_double(&num, 4)  ==  4 [num] assign_and_double
```

But my hunch stopped there...

Thank you if you know how to enlighten me about this!

**EDIT**

*I'm editing my question to give an update on Turing-complete languages.*

I suspect my little language to be Turing-complete because it meets the criteria for.

In compilation classes, we are taught how to compile from high level to low level (and/or from "pure to impure"), and in fact my question had more of a "practical" side because I would like to do the opposite. Beyond the fact that it is theoretically possible to compile a complete Turing-complete language to another, I wonder how this could be done. The particular example of pointers (C-like) interested me here (I "target" not to be too broad).

Indeed, I would like to be able to generalize a rough and trivial compilation from a very simple program written in C using pointers to my abstract machine (which may be similar to a concatenative language like [Joy](https://wiki.c2.com/?JoyLanguage) (as it is the implementation that inspired me, although Forth is also a close candidate)).

So the question is how to do this, or to make it less vague: what are the tracks to explore?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are asking?  Are you asking if it is Turing-complete?  Forth is Turing-complete, and I suspect your language is too, but we don't have a specification of which instructions it has so it's hard to be sure.  If it's Turing complete, any other Turing-complete language can be compiled into it.  See also https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/991/755.

Comment: @D.W. I edited my question in the hope that it would be more specific. I hope that's clearer?